# Naming in Django: useThis or use_this?

Tags: python, django

Programmers prefer different types of coding styles.

Sometimes I think that it is strange to use *class names* LikeThis and *field/method names* like_this.

What is your opinion? Use CaptionNames or underscore_names to delelop websites *powered with Django*?

Comment: What you call "strange" is recommended in PEP 8: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Django code is Python code, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the default way to go.

> A style guide is about consistency. 
>   Consistency with this style guide is
>       important.  Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency
>       within one module or function is most important.

Comment: while we are on the topic of PEPs and being pythonic - [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) "The Zen of Python" is always something interesting to come back to and read